# Trigger a blur event on an editable row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Hii,
I am using jqGrid for displaying data.I have a problem with inline editing.My customer wants to save a row on blur event.BTW I am using row editing.The jqGrid requires explicitly pressing enter to save a particular row.Is there a specific way to trigger a blur event on a row?
I tried different options like

```
$("tr#"+id,"table tbody").live('blur',function(e){

     $("#gridId").saveRow(id);

});
```

as well as

```
$(".editable").live('blur',function(e){

         $("#gridId").saveRow(rowId);

  });
```

But none of them worked.Both are getting triggered when I move out of the particular cell.
Is there a way to save the row once the user moves out of editing??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this works, but you can try to use onSelectRow event.

```
onSelectRow: function(rowid,status)
{
  if(!status)//deselected
  {
     if($("tr#" + rowid).attr("editable") == 1) //editable=1 means row in edit mode
        $("#gridId").saveRow(rowid);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the enter key like so...

```
var event = jQuery.event('keydown');
event.which = 13; 
$('tr input').trigger(event);
```

It may require some modifications depending on how jqGrid handles the keypress.

Comment: The problem here is that I am unable to capture a blur event for the row.If the blur event is captured some way for a row then $("#gridId").saveRow(rowId); works.The solution you provided works well at a cell level but not at a row level.
BTW thnx for your response